# how do i driveapp get files in folder alphabetically using google scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, drive

I'm getting files from a folder in google drive and then trying to insert a link to them in a spreadsheet. The problem is the files using the 
var ezIter = folderez.getFiles(); seem to come back in a random order. 
I'd like them to be in alphabetically order. Is this possible?

Here is my code currently. It works well but it is linking to the files out of order and that is messing everything up.

```
function getFiles() {

  var dApp = DriveApp;
  var vfolder = dApp.getFoldersByName("video").next();
  var yearfolder = vfolder.getFoldersByName("2018").next();
  var gamefolder = yearfolder.getFoldersByName("game1").next();
  var folderez = gamefolder.getFoldersByName("ez").next();
  var ezIter = folderez.getFiles();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(yearfolder+gamefolder);

  var i = 2;

  while (ezIter.hasNext()) {
    var file = ezIter.next();
    var name = file.getName();
    var url = file.getUrl();
    range = 'AC'+(i);
    var filename = 'ezvideo'+(i-1);
    var semi = ";";  
    var hyp = "=hyperlink(\"";
    var quot = "\"";
    var clos = ")";
    var title = hyp  + url + quot + semi + quot + filename + quot + clos;  // str='=hyperlink("' + f.getUrl() + '","' + f.getName() + '")';
    ss.getRange(range).setValue(title);   
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Rather than require sorted file return (which will unnecessarily increase processing time and API quota usage), why not simply properly compute which value of `i` to use, rather than assume it is ordered?

Comment: @tehhowch I thought of doing that, but They aren't always numbered sequentially ie they might go vf001, vf003, vf007... etc   and they don't always start with 1, it might be files vf0106 to vf0249

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how this API works, but this may help you sort files.

First, remove your `while` loop entirely and paste the following instead:

```
var files = [];

// creates an array of file objects
while (ezIter.hasNext()) {
    files.push(ezIter.next());
}

// sorts the files array by file names alphabetically
files = files.sort(function(a, b){
    var aName = a.getName().toUpperCase();
    var bName = b.getName().toUpperCase();

    return aName.localeCompare(bName);
});

files.forEach(function(file){
    var name = file.getName();
    var url = file.getUrl();
    range = 'AC'+(i);
    var filename = 'ezvideo'+(i-1);
    var semi = ";";  
    var hyp = "=hyperlink(\"";
    var quot = "\"";
    var clos = ")";
    var title = hyp  + url + quot + semi + quot + filename + quot + clos;  // str='=hyperlink("' + f.getUrl() + '","' + f.getName() + '")';
    ss.getRange(range).setValue(title);   
    i++;
});
```

**UPDATE:** Based on tehhowch's optimization suggestion, you can call `getName` once for each file like this:

```
var files = [];

// creates an array of file objects
while (ezIter.hasNext()) {
    var file = ezIter.next();
    files.push({name: file.getName(), url: file.getUrl()});
}

// sorts the files array by file names alphabetically
files = files.sort(function(a, b){
    var aName = a.name.toUpperCase();
    var bName = b.name.toUpperCase();

    return aName.localeCompare(bName);
});

files.forEach(function(file){
    var name = file.name;
    var url = file.url;
    range = 'AC'+(i);
    var filename = 'ezvideo'+(i-1);
    var semi = ";";  
    var hyp = "=hyperlink(\"";
    var quot = "\"";
    var clos = ")";
    var title = hyp  + url + quot + semi + quot + filename + quot + clos;  // str='=hyperlink("' + f.getUrl() + '","' + f.getName() + '")';
    ss.getRange(range).setValue(title);   
    i++;
});
```

Comment: Probably it is better for the OP to extract the name just once: `while (ezIter.hasNext()) { var file = ezIter.next(); files.push([file.getName(), file.getUrl()]); }`. That will prevent unnecessary API usage and speed up the sort considerably.

Comment: @tehhowch Sure, that would definitely be an optimization, especially if `getName` method makes network requests.

Comment: @tehhowch   Pardon my ignorance. If I put that in the while loop above, then what do I put in the for each in place of:
    var name = file.getName();
    var url = file.getUrl();   ?             
thank you for the suggestion, always looking to optimize my code

Comment: @tehhowch   I did try pasting in that code to pay with and it gave me an error on: var aName = a.getName().toUpperCase();      Type error can not find function in object.

Comment: @jerome you would need to modify the sort callback, since the object it is called on and thus the arguments it is passed are different. You can find many tutorials on sort callbacks online

Comment: @JeromeLearman I updated the answer with tehhowch's suggestion in mind.

Comment: @EmreErdoğan  Thank you!! You know your stuff!!